# cypher assign group of nodes to a relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

i'm working with Users assigned to a Grid location

```
(User)-[:PICK_UP]->(Grid)
```

With the query

```
 MATCH (u:User)-[:PICK_UP]->(g:Grid)-[:TO]-(g2:Grid)<-[:PICK_UP]-(u2:User) 
    RETURN g,g2,u,u2
```

I have the result [image]

In the image i have two groups of nodes, that represent the grid and its neighbors with users (red node). I would like to 'group'/create relations between the users nearby to a Spot node.

E.g. with the first group: grids 34, 40, 41, with the users 1,4,5,9. I would like to group the users in my query so i can get the result [user1, u4, u5, u9] and then those users i can assign them to a Spot, like this

[image]

Any suggestions?? 
Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

The thing to keep in mind is that your `(u:User)-[:PICK_UP]->(g:Grid)-[:TO]-(g2:Grid)<-[:PICK_UP]-(u2:User)` is matching a specific path, and while you see two groups in the graphical display, there are actually overlapping paths there.  Viewing your result in table mode might be helpful.

So onto answering your question!  Firstly, this was a tricky one, but a really cool one.  I think I've got a good solution:

```
MATCH path=(grid:Grid)-[:TO]-(other_grid:Grid)
WITH CASE WHEN ID(grid) < ID(other_grid) THEN ID(other_grid) ELSE ID(grid) END AS id_to_reject
WITH collect(DISTINCT id_to_reject) AS ids_to_reject

MATCH (grid:Grid)
WHERE NOT(ID(grid) IN ids_to_reject)

CREATE (spot:Spot)
WITH grid, spot

MATCH (grid)-[:TO|PICK_UP*1..6]-(user:User)

MERGE (user)-[:AT_SPOT]->(spot)
```

The first thing that the query does it to compare all `Grid` nodes which are related to each other.  For each of these pairs it passes on the `ID()` of the `Grid` node which is greater.  The `ID`s which aren't in the list are therefore the smallest in the group and can act as a representative of the group.  For each one of these representative `Grid` nodes we create a `Spot` node.

Using that node, it finds all `User` nodes within six hops via both `TO` and `PICK_UP` relationships.  That should give all users in the group (both the users of our representative grid as well as the users of the other grids).

Then it's a simple matter to `MERGE` a relationship from each user to the `Spot`.

Comment: Please let me know if this works!  I'm excited to know!

Comment: i tried the query, i changed the boundaries, bcs it generated more Spots than necessary e.g in one group the users, were pointing to 5 spots, and one user from them was pointing to 3 spots more. I changed  (g:Grid)-[:TO*1..2]-(o_g:G) and (grid)-[:TO|PICK_UP]-(u:Usr). But i have still some problems, now from each group,e.g from the group of grids 34,40,41(img 1)In the grid 41 and 34 there is only one user relation, in this case a spot was created for each user, and in the grid 40, with two users, one spot was created and both users are pointing to it.

Comment: I would like to add properties to the spot, e.g. 'name': Spot1, 2 .. n, 'time', which value will be taken from the user with smallest time value. I was thinking that i may need java for that, use the query to get the group of nodes with users or to get the users connected to a group, then assign the Relationship relation = spotNode.createRelationshipTo(graphDb.findNode(label, "name", userName), RelTypes.AT_SPOT)

Comment: Ah, shoot, I just realized that parts of `Grid` groups will be matched, meaning that you'll end up with extra spots...  Trying to think through that..

Comment: Ok, I've made a change which may help

Comment: Thank you @BrianUnderwood, there is a syntax error, in the first Where condition there is a "^" symbol under the "AS id_to_reject"" alias  "WHERE CASE WHEN ID(grid) < ID(other_grid) THEN ID(other_grid) ELSE ID(grid) END AS id_to_reject" Invalid input 'S': expected 'n/N' i couldn't find the error. Could you please have a look.

Comment: Ah, I think it's fixed.  I think it should have been a `WITH`, not a `WHERE`

Comment: now it runs. But .. :| it just generated the spot for one 'group' of nodes. Only the nodes 19 and 26 from the 1st image have the spot. The other group none

Comment: Interesting, are you sure?  I just tried it locally and it seems to have worked.  Maybe you can create some sample data on http://console.neo4j.org/ and use the "Share" button to share an example we can both work on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95481/discussion-between-andrea-hg-and-brian-underwood).